# Get POST data in functions.php from wp-admin post page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**Some description:**
I have created a custom jQuery plugin which allow to create markers on image. I want to storage coordinates of these markers in custom wordpress table. Also I created table called wp_markers.

Plugin appears in right place when I add image to the post (image is uploaded by advanced custom fields), plugin also create one hidden field and one text field to each marker dynamically. These data must be storaged in database.

**My problem:**
I can't access to $_POST array in functions.php in my theme when i click "Save" in wordpress edit page. How I should add values from my own custom fields to the custom wordpress table?

When I write `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>` in functions.php and click "Save", then appears an empty array. What is correct way to handle this data in WordPress?

Comment: Are you sure wordpress use POST method to save data? Maybe take a look on this side ...

Comment: I tried also `<?php var_dump($_REQUEST); ?> and this returns only $_GET data from the URL.

Comment: If your expected datas are on $_GET var, it means that wordpress use GET method to save datas. Is the $_GET variable empty? Does it contains the expected datas?

Comment: No, there are no expected data in the $_GET. WordPress using other way to save data, but i can't find any information how to handle it.

Comment: Try to handle this using your firefbug tool (or chrome equivalent) in the network tab. Do your scenario (edit page, save), keep trace in logs, and you will be able to get a trace of each call is done with which method, datas, headers, ...

Comment: I analyse some calls here http://demosite.center/wordpress/, it seems that a page called http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php is used with POST request method (when i try to save a page). But nothing is answered, maybe wordrpress simply save datas, without sending any datas in return ... sorry I can't help you anymore here :/

Comment: I know that data are sent to wp-admin/post.php, but modifing this file is not good practice, because when wordpress will upgrade to the new version this file will be overwriten. I want to do it in right way. Thank you.

Comment: I completely agree with you, changing core files is very rarely a good idea. Anyway, have you tried to debug step by step, and see where datas are?

Comment: They are definitely in post.php, but it must be way to handle it in other way than modyfing this file.